# What is a local operator in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, symmetry, locality, non-locality

In quantum mechanics, what exactly is meant by "local" operator?

What about a "global" or a "non-local" operator? Are these the same?

Can you also also help me understand what exactly is a local perturbation and a local symmetry?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A local operator is one whose action only depends on the value of the wave function (and its derivatives) at a single point.  Almost all the ordinary operators one encounters are local in this sense, including $\hat{x}$, $\hat{p}$, $\hat{L}_{z}$, etc.  The opposite of "local" in this context is not "global," but rather "nonlocal."

A nonlocal operator would act in something like the following way:
$$\hat{W}\psi\left(\vec{x}\right)=\int d^{3}x'\, W\left(\vec{x},\vec{x}'\right)\psi\left(\vec{x}'\right).$$
The nonlocality comes from the fact that the value of $\hat{W}\psi$ at a point $\vec{x}$ depends on the value of $\psi$ at other points. The condition for $\hat{W}$ to be Hermitian is $W\left(\vec{x},\vec{x}'\right)=W\left(\vec{x}',\vec{x}\right)^{*}$.

The use of the terms "local perturbation" and "local symmetry" are less clearcut.  A local perturbation might be one of two things.  It might be a perturbation (added to the Hamiltonian) that is represented by a local operator.  Or it might mean a position-dependent perturbation that goes to zero at spatial infinity.  (Without further context, it is not possible to know which is meant.  I requested a monograph from the library once, since it was supposed to be about "nonlocal solitons," thinking that it would cover solitary waves with nonlocal interactions like $\hat{W}$ above.  In fact, it turned out to be a book about non-*localized* solitonic phenomena.)

Having a local symmetry means that the symmetry transformation will be allowed to depend on position, but there may be other conditions applied.  Some people restrict the term "local symmetry" to mean a gauge symmetry of the second kind; other people use it to mean something different.

Comment: Okay, so a non-local operator may not mean it is a global operator, right?

Comment: @JoãoBravo Yes, the opposite of "local" in this context is "nonlocal," not "global."

Comment: Thank you! In regards to the last part of my post, can I say that a ***local symmetry*** is an invariance of the system to the application of a local operator? If that is the case, are global symmetries a subset of local symmetries?

Comment: But isn't "a *position-dependent perturbation* that goes to zero at spatial infinity" also described by a local operator that you add to the hamiltonian?

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but does saying that "a local symmetry means that the symmetry transformation will be *allowed to depend on position*" mean the same as saying that it is *an invariance of the system to the application of a local operator*? I want to be careful with subtleties.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand this answer: *"A local operator is one whose action only depends on the value of the wave function"* what wave function? Do you mean *"a local operator is such that its action on a state of the Hilbert space depends on the position"*?

Comment: Just to abuse terminology, the opposite of a local operator is not a global operator in the same sense that a the opposite of a local government (such as a city government) is any larger government (such as a state government or even a few nations signing treaties)... a "global government" is a much larger concept indeed.

Answer (score 9):

From a quantum informational perspective, given a multipartite state $\lvert\Psi\rangle$, a *local operation* is one that acts independently on each subspace. The distinction between *local* and *non-local* operations is an important one for example for the study of entanglement.

Consider for simplicity a *bipartite* state $\lvert\Psi\rangle$, that is, a state that can be written as $\lvert\Psi\rangle=\sum_{ij}c_{ij}\lvert i\rangle\otimes\lvert j\rangle$.
A simple example of *local* operation is some $A\equiv (A'\otimes I)$. This is an operation that only acts nontrivially on one part of the system. More explicitly, its action would then read:
$$A\lvert\Psi\rangle=\sum_{ij} c_{ij}(A'\lvert i\rangle)\otimes\lvert j\rangle.$$
As another example, an operation of the form $A'\otimes B'$ is also local, and its action on a *product* state $\lvert\psi\rangle\otimes\lvert\phi\rangle$ would read
$$\lvert\psi\rangle\otimes\lvert\phi\rangle\to (A'\lvert\psi\rangle)\otimes(B'\lvert\phi\rangle).$$
One notable property of local (unitary) operations is that they do not affect the entanglement (in a way that can be made precise).

Global operations are operations that are not local. Albeit in some contexts it's possible that "global" and "non-local" refer to different properties (for example an operation on a three-qubit system that only acts nontrivially on two of the three qubits might be referred to as a non-local, but also not global).

For a two-qubit system, an example of a global operation can be a CNOT, while a local operation is any single-qubit gate.

Comment: Thank you for the quantum information perspective!

Comment: Easily explained! Just one thing more if you could mention. The 1st eqn says that you have written the state in tensor product space as a product state ( as it's not a schmidt decomposition). On product states A acts on the 1st part and Identity acts on the 2nd part ( if there is no operator B) correct? But same thing happens for entangled states too. A acts on 1st part and identity or B acts on other. So is there no difference between the action of a local operator on products states and entangled states? Does a local operator acts in the same way on a product state and entangled state

Comment: @Shashaank the action of an operator is defined regardless of the states on which it is made to act

Comment: @glS thanks for the clarufication